# Did sql server 2005 sp3 stop the SQL service

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to install SQL server 2005 sp3. I need to know before if the installation need a reboot and if the installation will stop my SQL service. I got over 300 database on my server.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not, a reboot is required, it would seem prudent to manage the risk involved by scheduling a down window, just in case something unexpected happens during the install.

If you are talking about a mission-critical production server, I'd want to have any worse case scenarios catered for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The install of SP3 will require a reboot (at least it always has in the 10 or so I've done).